# Identify burned out component - top marking "WV4" then "60" turned sideways

Tags: identification

[image: photo of part of PCB with pointer close to suspect component]

Circuit board from welder is used to vary current, using foot pedal "amptrol". Current does not vary now, because of bad "amptrol". Everything else works well.

It looks like a surface mount diode, I'm not sure. It appears other parts on the circuit board are the same.

There is "WV4" then "60" turned sideways on top of part. The pointer is approx. 1/16"dia.

The bad part is approx 1 mm x 4 mm. I need the part identified and then repaired.

The welder is made in Italy. The part appears to have resin or something bubbling out of the corner.

Comment: Add a photo of the part.

Comment: ... and some punctuation. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words!

Comment: Didn't you try searching https://www.datasheetarchive.com/smd%20diode%20wv4-datasheet.html

Comment: you know finding a part with the information given can be hard to impossible especially considering that if you google wv4 diode you get multiple results, most likely they will be interchangeable with yours but never the less you should give more info and definitely improve your wording

Comment: Why do you think that part is faulty?

Comment: mick510ab - You added: "*part appears to have resin or something bubbling out of corner*" That resin or whatever did *not* come out of that part. That part doesn't contain soft, light-coloured resin - such a package is completely made of the hard black epoxy that you see (with the small silicon die inside). Therefore, as mentioned by *Spehro*, that is not evidence that the part is faulty. That resin (perhaps flux? grease? etc.) has not come from that part, but actually came from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

WV4 is BAT54S with 2 BAT54 Schottky diodes.

http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/wv

http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/b/a/bat54_series_nxp.pdf